# Change language to spanish

Tags: tcpdf

I'm trying to change my language to Spanish, but I'm having no luck.

Here is my code for setting that language, what else do I need to do in order to achieve this?

```
    $lg = Array();
    $lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
    $lg['a_meta_language'] = 'es';
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);
```

Comment: together with this setting you have to add `$pdf->SetFont('', '', 12);`

Comment: use fonts from the fonts directory in tcpdf

Comment: What font would work here? Does this translate my text for the pdf or no?

Comment: There is no translate. Font support make it nicely to present letters in pdf